# Do I need to assign \0 to malloc strings in c?

Tags: c

I have the following code to declare and assign a string on the heap.

```
char *string = malloc(10);
string[9] = '\0';
strncpy(string, "welcometotherealworld", 9);

printf("string: %s\n", string);
```

Do I have to manually set the `\0\` to ensure the string ends? `string[9] = '\0';`

Or, does `strncpy` do this for me?

Comment: Use calloc(10, sizeof(char)); to be sure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`strncpy` does not null terminate the destination array if the length of the source string (the second argument) is greater or equal than the value of the third argument.

So here:

```
strncpy(string, "welcometotherealworld", 9);
```

`strncpy` will not null terminate.

Answer (score 3):

Two things: First `malloc(10)` reserves 10 bytes, `string[10]` addresses the eleventh byte, so that is illegal. Second: Yes you have to set string[9] to null, because according to the [standard](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strncpy/?kw=strncpy) strncpy does not ensure the string is null terminated if the source string is longer than count.

Answer (score 0):

`welcometotherealworld` is definitely longer than `9` characters, so `strncpy` should not implicitly add a terminating character.

Answer (score 0):

`strncpy(dest, source, n)` copies at most `n` bytes from the buffer pointed to by `source` into the buffer pointer to by `dest`. However, if `strlen(source)` is greater than `n`, then `strncpy` will simply copy the first `n` bytes and will not terminate the string `dest` with a null byte because there is no space for it. Therefore to ensure that the buffer `source` is always null terminated, you must do it yourself. What you are doing will always keep your buffer pointed to by `string` null terminated.

Answer (score 0):

To insure a proper `'\0'` ending, code needs to set the `'\0'`.
`malloc()` does not initialize the the data in `string`.

```
char *string = malloc(10);
strncpy(string, "welcometotherealworld", 9 /* or 10 */);
string[9] = '\0';
```

`strncpy(char *s1, const char *s2, size_t n)` writes `n` `char` to `s1`.
It first uses `min(n, strlen(s2))` `char` from `s2`.
If more are needed, the remainder of `s2` is written with null characters.

Answer (score 0):

`strcpy` will always terminate the destination string with a `\0`. `strncpy` also *normally* `NULL` terminates the string, but may not do. It copies a maximum number of bytes (`n`) of the string, but unfortunately (in terms of a useful ABI) does not copy in a  NULL if the number of bytes to be copied (i.e. the length of the source string including the terminating `NULL`) exceeds the length specified (`n`) . So, if you copy the string `"1234567890"` (which is ten characters plus a `NULL`, so 11) and pass `10` as the last argument to `strncpy`, you will get an unterminated string of 10 characters.

Here are some safe routes around this:

```
dest = malloc(10); /* allocate ten bytes */
strncpy (dest, src, 10); /* copy up to 10 bytes */
dest[9] = 0; /* overwrite the 10th byte with a zero if it was not one already */

dest = malloc(10); /* allocate ten bytes */
strncpy (dest, src, 9); /* copy up to 9 bytes */
dest[9] = 0; /* make the 10th byte zero */

dest = calloc(10, 1); /* allocate and zero ten bytes */
strncpy (dest, src, 9); /* copy up to 9 bytes, leaving the NULL in */
```